# What kind of apparatus could this be?

Tags: siemens

[image]

I apologize in advance, if this isn't the right place to ask this. I want to find out, what kind of electronic device this is. The tape recorder is just on top of it, but I am talking about the device beneath it. It is integrated into a metal suitcase, it is manufactured by Siemens, and the keyboard doesn't have letters on it, but instead has weird combinations of letters on it, like OMN, OA etc.

Comment: IT'S A BOMB!!! RUN!!! :)

Comment: I didn't know Siemens manufactured explosives ;)

Comment: Looks like an old assembler :)

Comment: Closeup of keyboard and other legends may help, e.g. around the keyswitch on the left. (And is there a model number next to "Siemens"? And whatever you do, don't cut the blue wire.

Comment: You mean red wire...?

Answer (score 1):

May be an old plc programmer. The text of the three positions of the key may help to discover. Also the identification of the sub-D connectors. Could you tell us?

---

It seems to be a **PLC programmer** from the age of no-pc-at-home.
The PLCs had very little RAM (a few Kbs) and only proprietary interfaces. I have never seen a programmer that big, just handheld devices. 
In fact, nowadays Siemens programmers are pc-based devices but still called *suitcases*.

Comment: I have just zoomed in to the key switch on the image. I can make out 2 of the three words.  They're in German: "auslesen" (select), "einlesen" (read in), and the third position looks like "text <something> halt".

Comment: The key positions say: "Auslesen" "Einlesen" "Test bei Halt" which means: read, write, test on hold/test at hold

Comment: The Round connectors on the right say SS and MB, the parallel port beneath says DR

Comment: The LEDs next to the screen are saying: STAT, VKE, Betrieb (Operation)

Comment: Are there any key on the keyboard that says U, A, O, SP, SPN, E? Those are common Siemens plc commands. Any ref to S5 model?

Comment: Yes these keys are present on the keyboard